# configure slack with watcher on found

Tags: slack, elastic-found, elasticsearch-watcher

i have a web hook in slack and i have to configure it with watcher. the doc of elastic says this -

> To configure a Slack account in Watcher, you set the watcher.actions.slack.service property in elasticsearch.yml. You must set the url to your incoming webhook integration URL.

but found doesn't give access to yml.

For example, on the local server, the following snippet configures an account called notify-monitoring and sets the default sender name to Watcher.

```
watcher.actions.slack.service:
  account:
    monitoring:
      url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/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
      message_default:
        from: Watcher
```

how do i configure it on found??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while, but for anyone else who comes across this, the Elastic Cloud (previously branded as Found.io), now *does* support setting some (and only some!) `elasticsearch.yml` configuration through their web interface.

It's accessible under:

> Clusters => Cluster Name => Configuration => User Settings

I was able to insert the Slack notification settings there successfully!

IMPORTANT: this change does not propagate immediately. It took some time for me, so you might have to go get a cup of coffee while it's applied.

Also, another tip: You might find it easier to add a `default_account` for Slack, as follows:

```
watcher.actions.slack.service:
  default_account: monitoring
  account:
    monitoring:
      url: <your_slack_hook_url>
      message_defaults:
        from: watcher
```